# Could not find method id() for arguments [com.google.gms.google-services] none of the stack overflow solutions works

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart

`**A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

> Could not find method id() for arguments [com.google.gms.google-services] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1**`

I failed to find a solution for this error?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure that the google-services plugin is applied in the correct Gradle file. It is typically applied in the app/build.gradle file, and it should be at the bottom of the file.
   **The google-services plugin should be applied after all other dependencies.**
2. Ensure that you are using a compatible version of the google-services plugin. Check the latest version in the Google Services Gradle Plugin Release Notes.
   In your app/build.gradle file, make sure you have the correct version
3. Sync gradle files
   If the issue persists, double-check the syntax in your Gradle files for any typos or misconfigurations.